# google-datastore obtaining the correct blob item key for download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

In the google appengine datastore, there is a BlobKey (labled as csv). The key is in the following format: encoded_gs_file:we1o5o7klkllfekomvcndhs345uh5pl31l. I would like to provide a download button to save this information.

The web app is being run using dev_appserver.py and uses python 2.7 (Django) as the backend. Currently, a button exists, but when clicking on it, it returns a 404 error. The download link that the button provides is:

```
https://localhost:8080/data?key=encoded_gs_file:dwndjndwamwljioihkm
```

The interesting thing is that, when i go to localhost:8000/datastore and then navigate to the Blobstore Viewer, i can navigate to Entity Kind: **GsFileInfo**,  and there is a key generated. The problem is that it gives a 404. 
[image]
[image]

The other blob item next to is a png and if i use the key for that png, i get a download. What is wrong with the key, how can i get the write key from the datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still scratching my head in regards to your issue, but something that seems suspect is that `size` is `None` and `finalized` is `False` for your CSV file.

I looked back at your previous question ([google cloud: downloading as an CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102619/google-cloud-downloading-as-an-csv)) and noticed that you're not calling `.close()` on your GCS/blobstore file after you finish writing to it.

Maybe that will fix this.

Comment: could you please clarify as to where i would need to add .close().

Comment: In `generate_data_from_query()` add `f.close()` right before `blob_key = BlobKey(blobstore.create_gs_key(u'/gs' + gcs_filename))`